# Differences between config and vshost.config files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following situation.

I migrated a web service to another server, so I have to modify the endpoint with the name of the new server. The old server is going to shut down but, as long as there are connections, it will have to keep on. I have modified the configuration files, I did not think it necessary to modify the vshost.config files, I no longer have any more config files that I can modify

Is it possible that the vshost files are connecting to the web service with the old endpoint?

I would appreciate your answers. Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your application on the server, it refers to the actual config file. Though when you run through visual studio in debug mode, it will create vshost.config file which is nothing just visual studio hosted application and its config file. These files are used during debug mode and run of your application through visual studio. Once the application stopped, it is not used by the application.

Summary, Your application is using a config file not vshost.config (becasue it is meant for visual studio)